# Eclipse STS Hibernate error: "Fetching children of Database". org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, logging, slf4j

I have looked and tried various solutions dealing with the SLF4J related issue but nothing has worked. All I am trying to do is use the Hibernate plug in inside STS. I Simply click on the Hibernate perspective, Then the down arrow on my project and down arrow on the Database and this exception occurs.

I saw in the properties of the Hibernate console that there is an Eclipse log file dir to a logback. Do I have to setup logback in my pom somewhere?

I used my setup from eclipse tutorials I found online. The only difference is that I'm using the specific STS version and a more recent version of Spring and Hibernate. I have setup the hibernate conifig and the console config.

Any help to get this Hibernate plugin working correctly with Logging using Maven would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

The following is my setup:

STS v3.2, MySQL DB, vFabric Server (comes with STS), Using Maven

POM versions:

```
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.2</org.slf4j-version>
    <org.apache.tiles>2.2.2</org.apache.tiles>      
    <mysql>5.1.24</mysql>               
    <hibernate.version>4.1.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
```

Spring, Hibernate & Logging sections:

```
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>               
   <!-- Saw this fix online and was trying - doesn't work, temp commented out
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>           
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            Exclude SLF4j to avoid version conflicts (we have 1.6.2, this drags in 1.6.1)
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency> 
    END Saw this fix online and was trying - doesn't work, temp commented out -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>     


<!-- Logging -->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR2</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.JDBCMetaDataDialect.getTables(JDBCMetaDataDialect.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.processTables(JDBCReader.java:476)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

---

Thanks! I actually ended up just commenting out logging for a couple minutes while I let the Hibernate reveng tool do its thing. Per this post forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2441023 I then readded them after and all is well! :D –

Answer (score 1):

The `NoSuchMethodError` on `LocationAwareLogger.log()` method with 6 arguments is symptomatic of a slf4j binding with version prior to 1.6 on the class path. The 'mvn dependency:tree' should indicate as much, i.e that you have an older binding, say `slf4j-log4j-1.5.jar`.

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up just commenting out logging for a couple minutes while I let the Hibernate reveng tool do its thing. Per this post https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2441023 I then readded them after and all is well! :D